# Fragment Table Overflow router cisco (strange Behavior)

Tags: cisco, routing, mtu

I am getting this error message many times in my Router Cisco :

```
%IP_VFR-4-FRAG_TABLE_OVERFLOW: Tunnel1: the fragment table has reached its maximum threshold 16

%IP_VFR-4-FRAG_TABLE_OVERFLOW: Tunnel1: the fragment table has reached its maximum threshold 16
```

Could anyone familar with this kind of error and know the impact on the router?

Thank You

EDIT:

```
interface Tunnel1 
 ip address 192.168.144.1 255.255.255.252 
 ip mtu 1500 
 ip nat outside 
 ip virtual-reassembly 
 ip tcp adjust-mss 1400 
 delay 55000 
 tunnel source 192.168.0.1 
 tunnel destination 192.168.10.2
```

Comment: We need to see your entire configuration to be sure, but the router is likely fragmenting packets (or receiving fragmented packets), and is not able to keep track of them all.  Make sure your tunnel MTU is set correctly.

Comment: @RonTrunk , thank you, my tunnel MTU is configured like this, I have specified 1500 for MTU and 1400 for the negociation of MSS. ' interface Tunnel1 ip address 192.168.144.1 255.255.255.252 ip mtu 1500 ip nat outside ip virtual-reassembly ip tcp adjust-mss 1400 delay 55000 tunnel source 192.168.0.1 tunnel destination 192.168.10.2'

Comment: Increase the size of the table: `ip virtual-reassembly max-reassemblies 128 timeout 15`